# Finding the incorrect statement out of these

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

I got this question from somewhere. It is easy but I am not able to find the incorrect option out of these.

> Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$. Let $m_A$ denote the minimal
> polynomial and $c_A$ denote the characteristic polynomial then, Find the incorrect option(s)
>
> 1. $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue $\iff m_{A}(\lambda)=0.$
> 2. The minimal polynomial of a matrix is unique
> 3. If $P(x)$ is a polynomial such that $P(A)=0\implies  m_{A}|p_A$
> 4. $m_A(x)|c_A(x)$
> 5. Every irreducible factor of $c_A(x)$ is also a factor of $m_A(x)$ and conversely
> 6. Every root of $c_A(x)$ is also a root of $m_A(x)$ and conversely
> 7. $\deg(m_A(x))\geq $ number of distinct eigenvalues.

**My Efforts**

$(1).(2),(3), (4),(6)$ These are all true as I have proved them.

I have doubts in $(5)$ and $(7)$

I need some hints. I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they're all true.   For $(5)$ look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825848/showing-that-minimal-polynomial-has-the-same-irreducible-factors-as-characterist).  $(7)$ looks easy.